# Facebook and Twitter for both login and sign up

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter-oauth

One my landing page, Facebook and Twitter are the two options to signup for new users. Is it possible to make the same two buttons in the landing page a login button as well for existing users?

(Im not a techincal person)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is technically possible...

PS: though not possible for a not technical person (since it requires some programming)

Comment: Thanks! Would you know any sites that use this example? Also how difficult would it be for a technical person to do?

Comment: @user2220027: not difficult at all. And I'd say **any** site that uses FB/twitter authentication uses the same code for both signing in and signing up. The quick example: http://tv.com (it doesn't have twitter button but it doesn't change anything)